# Tomcat intentionally ignore startup errors

Tags: java, tomcat

With next release my app needs Java 8 instead of Java 7.
I have create `error.html` page and defined it in `web.xml` and idea was to show user error page if he has older version of Java

The problem is that during Tomcat startup it throws `java.lang.Unsupported.UnsupportedClassVersionError`
and it doesnt even serves my application so no error page is displayed

Is there any way to ignore all startup errors and let app stars.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Who are you calling "user", the administrator of the system where Tomcat is installed ?

Comment: No average joe who acceses web app

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you're asking, but IMHO this still qualifies as an answer:

> show user error page if he has older version of Java

for the average Joe (as you clarify in a comment): Does that mean that you're serving applets in 2018? Why else would the average joe have Java?

Regarding the error message that you want to ignore: When tomcat's startup routines report an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`, you probably run Java8 code on Java7 (or Java9 code on Java8) and you should fix this instead of asking how to run a half-defunct app that has been compiled with the wrong java version.

As you don't provide the stacktrace with the exception: Any exception (or even error) that you don't handle will lead to tomcat's default behavior. If this is an `Error` that is triggered within your own code, you can catch it instead of throwing it down to tomcat. I wouldn't recommend it, but that's the only opportunity that I'm seeing. The odds are that your error page will reference code with the wrong class version as well, thus you might not be able to show this error page anyways.

Fix the underlying issue rather than trying to play tricks on the underlying innocent infrastructure that just does what it's supposed to do.